# How to create splitter window in dialog, attach example

Tags: mfc, dialog, splitter

I am practice on splitter window, I reference to this web site,

[Creating a Splitter Window in a Dialog Box in Three Easy Steps](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/splitter/tutorials/article.php/c4705/Creating-a-Splitter-Window-in-a-Dialog-Box-in-Three-Easy-Steps.htm)

when I build it, some thing error I cant solve it, like follow code...

```
Out of memory creating a splitter pane.
Error: Trying to create object which is not DECLARE_DYNCREATE 
or DECLARE_SERIAL: CDialogEx.

Out of memory creating a splitter pane.

Error: Trying to create object which is not DECLARE_DYNCREATE 
or DECLARE_SERIAL: CDialogEx.
```

the link for download this example, please rewrite the example,

[splitter dialog example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rt4llh7cufg9xmk/splitterwindow_dialog.rar)

the other feature, I want to create a two panel with button and static

and listcontrol item.

thanks guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a dialog base application. Just use the wizard. Create a SDI sample with a `CFormView`... integrate the splitter window later.

It doesn't make sense to me to create a dialog and to integrate all the `CFrameWnd` features into a `CDialog`...

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `CDialog1` with `CWnd` then solved this problem.

```
ccc.m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CWnd);
m_cSplitter.CreateView(0,0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CWnd),
    CSize(100,100), &ccc);
m_cSplitter.CreateView(0,1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CWnd),
    CSize(100,100), &ccc);
```